# Java rmi proxy code example

Tags: java, proxy, rmi

I don't know very well how to create a proxy in java rmi. My client A invokes the server B (unicast) successfully. Now i want that the client A invokes a proxy server C wich invokes the server B. How i can create the proxy? I need a code example to adapt at my situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proxy just one remote interface, it's easy: just write another implementation of it that looks up and calls the real implementation via RMI, and binds itself to a Registry that the client can lookup.

If you want to do it for arbitrary remote interfaces, it's highly non-trivial, trust me, if you are going to get the proxy to do anything useful, such as access control, SSL, etc. There are commercial products that do this, and I vend one of them.

Comment: The proxy that i want to implement is a remote proxy and i need a source code example to use as guideline

Comment: @user1421236 Why? Surely there's enough information above for you to grasp the concept? SO isn't a coding service.